# is it possible to extract certain strings based off a predefined white-space count?

Tags: php

So after several Advil's I think I need help

I am trying to make a script that lets the user upload a .txt file, the file will look like this as an example

```
           EXT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - DAY

           Police vehicles remain in the parking lot.  The determined
           female reporter from the courthouse steps, MELINDA FUENTES
           (32), interviews Comandante Chitt, who holds a napkin to his
           jaw, like he cut himself shaving.

                               MELINDA
                     < Comandante Chitt, how does it
                     feel to get shot in the face? >

                               COMANDANTE CHITT
                     < Not too different than getting
                     shot in the arm or leg. >

                               MELINDA
                     < Tell us what happened. >

                               COMANDANTE CHITT
                     < I parked my car.
                         (indicates assault vehicle
                          in donut shop)
                     He aimed his weapon at my head.  I
                     fired seven shots. He stopped
                     aiming his weapon at my head. >

           Melinda waits for more, but Chitt turns and walks away into
           the roped-off crime scene. Melinda is confused for a second,
           then resumes smiling.

                               MELINDA
                     < And there you have it... A man of
                     few words. >
```

Ok, so based off of this what I want to do is this:

The PHP script looks at the file and counts 35 white spaces, since all files will have the same layout and never differ in white spaces I chose this as the best way to go.

for every 35 white spaces extract character 36 until the end of line.

Then tally up $character++

so in the end the output would look like

```
-----------------------------------
It looks like you have 2 characters in your script

Melinda
Commandante Chitt
-----------------------------------
```

using PHP to select distinct names, and use the `strtolower()` to lower case the strings and `ucfirst()` to make the first letter upper-case

thats my project,

I'm at the stage where I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to count white-spaces and everything after that white space until the first white-space after the word IS a character name

Comment: Why did you ask this twice? Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676098/php-how-can-i-get-certain-keywords-form-a-text-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html><body><pre><?php
        $story = "           EXT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - DAY

           Police vehicles remain in the parking lot.  The determined
           female reporter from the courthouse steps, MELINDA FUENTES
           (32), interviews Comandante Chitt, who holds a napkin to his
           jaw, like he cut himself shaving.

                               MELINDA
                     < Comandante Chitt, how does it
                     feel to get shot in the face? >

                               COMANDANTE CHITT
                     < Not too different than getting
                     shot in the arm or leg. >

                               MELINDA
                     < Tell us what happened. >

                               COMANDANTE CHITT
                     < I parked my car.
                         (indicates assault vehicle
                          in donut shop)
                     He aimed his weapon at my head.  I
                     fired seven shots. He stopped
                     aiming his weapon at my head. >

           Melinda waits for more, but Chitt turns and walks away into
           the roped-off crime scene. Melinda is confused for a second,
           then resumes smiling.

                               MELINDA
                     < And there you have it... A man of
                     few words. >";
$_ = null;
if (preg_match_all('/\s{35}(.*)/m',$story,$_))
{
  $unique_characters = array_unique(array_map(create_function('$a','return ucfirst(strtolower(trim($a)));'),$_[1]));

  echo "-------------------------\r\n";
  echo "It looks like you have ".count($unique_characters)." characters in your script\r\n";
  echo "\r\n";
  array_map(create_function('$a','echo "{$a}\r\n";'),$unique_characters);
  echo "-------------------------";
}
?></pre></body></html>
```

You will notice `$_[1]` returns all the characters names found. Then, you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to find only the new characters (and display them as you have done).

**EDIT**
Added an update that does the work as requested. Also a working example (feel free to copy-paste to your own file and run it). Also-also, please excuse my short-hand and use of array_map, create_function, etc. ;p

Comment: hmmm, think there is something wrong somewhere, the PHP stops execution and shows a blank page. Gonna take some time and see if i can find the problem

Comment: @s2xi: chances are the SO formatting make the character names (and general story) mis-aligned. Take your original story clipping and place it in the $story variable yourself and try. Remember it needs 35 spaces before the name to match (otherwise the `preg_match_all` will fail, thus a blank page).

Comment: oh, hmmm ya sometimes you overlook the slightest details and wonder why nothing works ;)